# When I use Ajax sweet Alert doesn't show image. I'm working with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, sweetalert

When I use Ajax sweet Alert doesn't show image. I'm working with laravel.

This is my code, if I delete the ajax function or I use a image from another website it works.

I really have no clue, I think laravel need some kind of authetication from a Ajax request. Please help me out!

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.confirmation').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
        var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
        warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);

        });

         function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this team!",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
              })
              .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Checking...",
                        text: "Please wait",
                        icon: icons,
                        button: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false
                      });
                      $.ajax({
                        url: linkURL,
                        type: 'GET', 
                        success: function(result){
                        swal("The team was deleted!");
                    }
                });


                } else {
                  swal("The team was NOT deleted!");
                }
              });
          }

    });
```

Comment: And the varible icons is declared i the view like this `var icons = '{{ URL::asset('/icons/loading.gif') }}';`

Comment: have you checked if the url to the image returns the img? Because if it doesn't it has nothing to do with sweetalert

Comment: Yes it does, i even used it in the web site @GaimZz

Comment: I checked sweet alert documentation, it is never said that you can use custom url img to set icon you want to, so that might be the issue

Comment: It does, it works fine when I don't use Ajax

Comment: mmmm I see your problem now, you are trying to access a php variable with javascript!!!

Comment: I assume you have your reason not to put the url directly into the ajax, if thats the case the logic where you set the 'var icons' needs to be on JS

Comment: the var icon is on JS, it is render by blade in laravel

Comment: I think it might just not be loading on time.

Comment: that can't be because icon is set first, plus you SHOULD definetly NOTmix js with php really bad practice :S

Comment: The ajax call is asynchronous and because of that it has a different timeline than the swal with the title "checking". they are independent from each other and the result of this ajax call doesn't change anything on the swal which has already been executed. The problem seems to be with the "var icons" which we don't have a clue what really is. Plus you have to check which sweet alert you are using (there are a few like sweet alert, sweet alert2, ...) and the documentation and version. I think in a certain case you have the option imageUrl

Comment: I believe that Laravel only does some kind of authentication (crsf) if the ajax were with method "post"